# How to create a side scroller effect with images?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimage

I want to add some images (clouds) in the backgrounds of my app and create a effect of endless side scroller with them. That them keep popping from the left and keep going to the right.

I tried to implement that way:

```
class AnimateClouds: UIImageView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        animateClouds()
    }


    func animateClouds() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay:0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
            self.center.x = self.center.x

            }) { (completed) -> Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(50, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: { () -> Void in

                    // self.center.x = self.center.x - (self.superview?.frame.size.width)! / 3

                    self.center.x = self.center.x + (self.superview?.frame.size.width)! //+ (self.frame.size.width) * 2
                    }, completion: { animationFinished in

                        self.removeFromSuperview()


                })
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think that look good, and besides, I have to create a lot of clouds images in my storyboard and change their custom class. What's the better way to do that? I'm *not* making this app in Sprite Kit.

Comment: Do you have the cloud images in your story board ? Or you want to add the cloud images programatically ?

Comment: right now i have the images in my storyboard. But i think programatically is the best way to solve this. What do you think?

Comment: If you have way too many cloud images and don't want to clutter the storyboard it is better to add it programatically. So what I see is you need to move cloud images from left to right continuously right?

Comment: yes. I want them to appear before the left edge of the screen and vanish after the right edge. In the meantime, i want new clouds that keep popping to create this illusion of endless.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you want to move the cloud images left to right endlessly. When you want to have such animation, it is easy to write animation but making the animation look smooth and visually great is the thing that really matters.

So you're saying there are multiple cloud images in your story board, which means that all of these cloud images will be appearing at different position (origin) of the screen, this means when they travel from left to right, the duration required to travel from origin to right most end of the screen is different for each of the cloud images.

So not only the code to animate the cloud images matter, the duration of the animation matters as well. So you need to calculate the duration carefully and animate the cloud image for that amount of duration.

So that's lotta theory lets see a code snippet which achieves the desired animation effect.

```
func animateCloud(cloud: UIImageView) {
//Assuming the cloud image will take 60 seconds to travel from
//left most point to the right most point of view controller's view
//and determining the speed at cloud travels
let cloudSpeed = 60.0/view.frame.size.width

//Since each cloud images are at different position (origin)
//The distance from each cloud to right end of screen will be different and
//The time taken (duration) by the each cloud to travel to right end of view will be different
let duration = (view.frame.size.width - cloud.frame.size.width) * cloudSpeed

UIView.animateiWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(duration), delay:0.0, options:.CurveLinear, animations: {
    cloud.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
}, completion: {
      cloud.frame.origin.x = -cloud.frame.size.width
      self.animateCloud(cloud) // For endless animation
})
}
```

This should do the trick. You can add as many images you want and then call the animateCloud() method to animate the cloud images.

Comment: I'm getting a error: "Cannot convert value of type ‘() -> ()’" on the line "cloud.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame...." 

Another question: i implement this via View Controller and call the function in the viewDidLoad or create a class and change the custom class of the images?

Comment: I am able to execute the above snippet successfully without any errors. If you're getting the error replace the animations block with this :
animations: { () -> Void in
    cloud.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
}

Comment: That don't solve my problem. I keep needed to create a lot of clouds image to create the effect. With this code i can't create the effect of endless clouds. How i can do that without the need of create clouds images in my storyboard?

Comment: You can call this in viewDidAppear of the ViewController. What do you mean by changing the  custom class of images ?

Comment: can you edit the code above? I think i'm doing something wrong. The error keeps popping.

Comment: i changed to "completion: { animationFinished in
                self.animateCloud(cloud) // For endless animation
        })
    }
"

And it worked, but the animation didn't restart after the cloud vanish in the right side of the screen

Comment: I add a .Repeat in the function to create the loop. But how can i make to the image appear before the left frame of the screen?

Comment: I have updated the code to make image appear before the left frame of the screen.